# Netbeans/JPA change owning side of many to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans, generated

I'm using netbeans "Entity classes from database" function to generate my entity classes. Sadly, netbeans chooses the wrong manytomany relationship owner. I have for example a user and group table which are related via many to many. In my case the group entity is the owner with @JoinTable and User has the "MappedBy" annotation. How can I make User to the owning entity. I could change it manually but after generating it again from database, it will be overwritten. This is really annoying. Any ideas?

Regards, Manu

Comment: Which version are you using? Have you already checked the bug tracker of Netbeans? Had some problems in the past with manytomany

Comment: I'm already on the latest version 8.0.2. I created a bug -> https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=253443